# Promise.all should be rejected, but is actually fulfilled?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm newer to JavaScript and thought I understood the basics of Promises, but I am definitely missing something here.

The basic idea here is I am chaining a couple of promises together.

`promise3` does some initial work and if it succeeds, then we do some more work. The second stage of this chain is a couple of promises, `promise1` and `promise2`. Because `promise2` is rejected, the end result I had expected was that `Promise.all` rejects, and therefore I expected the result in `Promise.allSettled` to also be rejected.

However, what I am observing is that the first promise in the chain here determines the result of the chain - if it is resolved then the result is resolved, but if it is rejected then result is rejected.

Why is this the case?

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(1);
const promise2 = Promise.reject(2)
const promise3 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promises = [promise1, promise2];

const p = [ promise3.then(Promise.all(promises)) ]

Promise.allSettled(p).
  then((results) => results.forEach((result) => console.log(result.status)))
```

Comment: `.then(Promise.all(promises))` - `.then()` expects at least one callback and not a (fulfilled) `Promise`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your code is incorrect. `then` expects a callback, but you provide a value of `Promise.all(...)`

Corrected code is

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(1);
const promise2 = Promise.reject(2)
const promise3 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promises = [promise1, promise2];

const p = [ promise3.then(() => Promise.all(promises)) ]

Promise.allSettled(p).
  then((results) => results.forEach((result) => console.log(result.status)))
```